# Should the Debian Repository URL end with "/"?

Tags: debian, apt

This may not be a problem because it will work regardless of whether the URL ends with `/`.

I just wonder if it has a standard specification?

The following are from the official [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list). Some URLs end with `/`, and some do not.

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into the manual page `man sources.list`, it would appear that the standard way is to have URIs *without* trailing slash. But as you said, both variants work in practice.